# Only first media query working

Tags: css, media-queries

When using media queries, only the first set seems to work and I don't know why. If I swap them around, then still, only the first one works. I've tried changing from max-width to min-width, I've tried removing the and condition, I've tried removing all my Javascript. I've tried removing all my CSS, having only the media queries with body {display:none}. The media queries are at the end of my stylesheet. Viewport meta is correct (see below).

None of these attempts corrected my problem. Anyone got any idea why this is happening? I've worked with @media a hundred times and never have I had this problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

@media (max-width: 740px) and (min-width: 420px) {
    .product {
        width:45% !important;
        margin:10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    }

    .products-container select {
        width:85%;
    }   
}​

@media (max-width: 340px) {
    body {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

*Update*
I've checked FireFox's console. I'm actually getting the following error:
Dangling combinator. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

I get what it's trying to say, but there's nothing wrong with the queries' syntax.

Comment: You are aware that these media queries don't cater for widths between 340px and 420px.. and also for widths > 740px...right?

Comment: @Danield I am. These media queries are meant to resize products between 420px and 740px and then set body's display to none when less than 340px. First query works, second one is ignored.

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/VRWdd/ - the media queries are working fine - ie BOTH media queries work together

Comment: That's weird... if any rule works fine when is in first place, there's nothing incorrect in the sintax... Well, for be sure try to pass the css validator, and check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out.

There somehow was a hidden character in the CSS. This is odd considering that I typed everything else myself, maybe Dreamweaver put it there? A glitch maybe? Anyway, copying it over to MS Word and pasting it back into Dreamweaver fixed it.

P.S Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use Notepad++ or something to markup? Sometimes I write a whole document (css, html) and don't check the encoding. Change the encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 displays me strange characters (like [e+v], that stuff).

Comment: @Arkana Nope I write directly in Dreamweaver. It's just odd because I've never had a problem with this before. Then again, on a different occasion, my Dreamweaver crashed and replaced all my CSS with just spaces, so guess it can't always be trusted :)

Comment: So, can you mark your answer as correct? For help other users who came here with a similar question :) (Off topic, if my DW does that to me the scream will be listen in Omicron Persei 8 xD)

Comment: @Arkana Haha, ohhh and it's even worse if you don't have back-ups! I've marked the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `media queries` as they are now, kick in when the screen has width of

0-340px (second media query) and

420px-740px (first media query)

they don't cater for widths between 340px and 420px.. and also for widths > 740px

But certainly, BOTH media queries are working....

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/VRWdd)**

Comment: That's why it doesn't make any sense, because they aren't working on my side. I've checked the console - I've updated my question with what it says.