# Only one media query is working but i do not know why

Tags: css

Not all my media queries work, the query of 1200px works fine, but the query of 960px doesn't work either when I swap them around

I now have this:

```css
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        hr.splitter {
            margin-top: 335px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 960px) {
        .inside-container-tabs {
            width: 800px;
        }
    }
```

I see no errors in it so it should just work right?

Just as Hiriji has tried in this post, I have tried, but javascript and removing the rest does not work either.
[Only first media query working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942359/only-first-media-query-working)

Someone who can help me with this?

**Edit 1**

This is the exact code i'm using, and its working fine here..
https://codepen.io/WimTH/pen/rNaNXPQ

Comment: Why use `em` when it is recommended to use absolute `px` in `media-queries` ?

Comment: @johannchopin No idea why I do that didn't know I should use px. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/votu1nzy/

Comment: Its working fine in my pc `check your class name with element` @WimTH

Comment: I made a code pen with exactly the same code and it works just fine there..

Comment: https://codepen.io/WimTH/pen/rNaNXPQ

Comment: @johannchopin — Who recommends that? `em` is fine.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Since people can't reproduce the problem with the code you have, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Quentin The problem is that the exact same code works in code pen, so I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WimTH — The problem is that if you can't reproduce it, we can't identify it. If you can't reproduce it in code pen then whatever you are including there doesn't include the problem!

Comment: @Quentin No, I was already afraid of that. Could it be due to visual studio code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that it is indeed not due to the code but to chrome. I have tried all the time to check with the device toolbar if I was doing it right. Somehow it doesn't work with that .. but if I make the whole page smaller it will work.
Thank you for all the suggestions and help

Resolved this problem by adding this to my head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```